# Приоритет горячих клавиш

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, kde

Opensuse 13.2(kde) + intelliJ IDEA

Некоторые горячие клавиши используются как в idea, так и рабочим столом. Например, хочется вызвать какое-то действие в idea, а вызывается служебное приложение рабочего стола. Если у IDEA, в настройках окна, отключить "*Использовать глобальные комбинации клавиш*", то все отключаются абсолютно все системные сочетания, включая <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

**Есть ли возможность настроить приоритет горячих клавиш у одного приложения, над всеми остальными?** Так чтобы глобальные сочетания работали, лишь в том случае, если у приложения нет этого сочетания.
Вариант с переназначением клавиш в IDEA или во всех приложениях, в которых такие же сочетания, не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Нет нельзя. На то и существуют глобальные клавиши, что бы работать всегда и везде и локальные, что бы работать только в этом приложении.
При этом с глобальными клавишами не должны конфликтовать глобальные, по-этому в Linux, почти в каждой нативном приложении, есть возможность изменять локальные клавиши, а также в каждом DE можно изменить глобальные клавиши, по своему вкусу и удобству.

Измените или локальные комбинации в idea или глобальные в kde.